# import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('organizer') error

Tags: ros, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS so probably my error is silly. I'm trying to run this open source [project](https://github.com/nildo/organizer-baxter) on Baxter. I have pasted the master branch under ros_ws/src. When I try to run the right_hand_camera_srv.py file like that, rosrun organizer-baxter-master right_hand_camera_srv.py, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/ros_ws/src/organizer-baxter-master/src/right_hand_camera_srv.py", line 3, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('organizer')
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 159, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 198, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 190, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: organizer
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/anton/ros_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200992/import-roslib;-roslib.load_manifest(%27organizer%27)-error/) by [Anton Belev](https://answers.ros.org/users/21381/anton-belev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a rosbuild package.

It looks like it's expecting to be placed in a folder named `organizer` but instead you've placed it in a folder named `organizer-baxter-master`. You may want to try renaming the folder to see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0